# adding a letter before order id

Tags: magento2

I want to concatenate a string 'P' with the increment_id variable in .html file of email template without affect the translation , but I don't know why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p class="order-number">
                <strong>
                    {{trans 'Order # : P%increment_id' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}
                </strong>
            </p>
```

This should solve your issue !

**UPDATE**

I think the only way is via a templatevar. Here is an example on how to it for new order email:

on etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"        type="vendor\module\Preferences\Emails\OrderSender" />
```

At vendor\module\Preferences\Emails create file OrderSender.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Preferences\Emails;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;


class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
    protected $paymentHelper;
    protected $orderResource;
    protected $globalConfig;
    protected $addressRenderer;
    protected $eventManager;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     * @param OrderIdentity $identityContainer
     * @param Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param OrderResource $orderResource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        parent::__construct( $templateContainer, $identityContainer, $senderBuilderFactory, $logger, $addressRenderer, $paymentHelper, $orderResource, $globalConfig, $eventManager);
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
        $this->globalConfig = $globalConfig;
        $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare email template with variables
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        parent::prepareTemplate($order);

        // Add isquotation variable
        $templateVars = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars();

        $custom_increment_id = $order->getData('increment_id');
            $templateVars['custom_increment_id '] = 'P'. $custom_increment_id ;    
        
    }
}
```

On your code:

```
<p class="order-number">
                <strong>
                    {{trans 'Order # : %increment_id' increment_id= custom_increment_id |raw}}
                </strong>
            </p>
```

Comment: thanks for you rep , yes , but it affects the translation , and i don't want that :\

Comment: Check my updated answer please :) dont forget to upvote / mark as answer it it solve dyour problem